# How to identify executable path with its PID on AIX 5 or more

Tags: path, aix, ps

### On AIX 5 or 6, `ps -ef` shows the executable full path randomly. Why? And how to determine it?

I found many threads throughout the Internet and also Unix & Linux and [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606041/1195001) about finding the path of a process and so far I haven't succeeded in applying any method.
I keep falling into having `proftpd` shown instead of having a path. 
I finally read the `man ps` of AIX and find this :

> CMD
>
> (-f, -l, and l flags) Contains the command name. Under the -f flag, ps tries to determine the current command name and arguments both of which may be changed asynchronously by
>               the process. These are then displayed. Failing this, the command name as it would appear without the option -f, is written in square brackets.

I want to be sure to understand what it means when I have the following output:

```
 ps -ef (truncate output)
root 44900     1   0 11:49:36      -  0:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)
nobody 31986 14976   0   13 feb      -  0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -f /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

For the `httpd` daemon, it does show the full path but doesn't show the full path for `proftpd`.
First question is why are some processes shown with full path and some aren't?

The second question is for that case :

Can I assume that the path of the `proftpd` is the first I'll find typing `whereis` as `root` ?

In my case :

```
 whereis proftpd
 proftpd: /etc/proftpd.conf /usr/sbin/proftpd
```

<strike>So I assume that the running deamon is `/usr/sbin/protfpd ?`  Am I correct ?</strike>

---

**Edit 2**:

Let me answer that part: NO I can't make such an assumption -- it is not relevant at all. I finally found out that the daemon was running from `/opt/proftpd`, which is not even in the root path.

The "why does `ps -ef` work that way" is still to determine, and also: is there any other way to find out what is the real path knowing the PID?

---

**Edit 1**:
Here's the proof that my AIX system are not supporting `exe` link in `/proc/<PID>`.
I test this against AIX versions 5.3.9.0 and 6.1.7.15:

```
ls -al /proc/44900/*
-rw-------    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/as
-r--------    1 root     nobody          128 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/cred
--w-------    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/ctl
lr-x------   53 root     nobody            0 13 jan 16:07 /proc/44900/cwd -> /
-r--------    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/map
-r--r--r--    1 root     nobody          448 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/psinfo
-r--------    1 root     nobody         1024 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/sigact
-r--------    1 root     nobody         1520 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/status
-r--r--r--    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 /proc/44900/sysent

/proc/44900/fd:
total 5483376
dr-x------    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 ..
-r--r--r--    1 root     nobody         5005 12 jul 2004  3
-r--r--r--    1 root     nobody         8655 13 nov 15:13 5
-r--r--r--    1 root     nobody         1607 13 nov 15:12 6
--w-------    1 root     nobody   2378419349 13 jan 16:06 7
--w-------    1 root     nobody    423405131 13 jan 16:06 8

/proc/44900/lwp:
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 ..
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 99075

/proc/44900/object:
total 90312
dr-x------    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     nobody            0 14 jan 09:42 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system      1268973 16 okt 2012  a.out
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           15265 12 jul 2004  jfs.10.5.12513
-r--r--r--    1 bin      bin         8587637 23 mei 2008  jfs.10.5.16405
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin         9281793 23 sep 2008  jfs.10.5.4131
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           11019 01 okt 2007  jfs.10.5.4149
-r--r--r--    1 bin      bin          162078 19 jun 2008  jfs.10.5.4169
-r--r--r--    1 bin      bin         1161414 23 sep 2008  jfs.10.5.4171
-r--r--r--    1 bin      bin          379513 19 jun 2008  jfs.10.5.4943
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           96495 19 jun 2008  jfs.10.5.5248
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system     17160842 05 okt 2011  jfs2.51.3.266241
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system       315783 11 mei 2006  jfs2.51.3.266246
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system      3237612 05 okt 2011  jfs2.51.3.266262
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system       125958 25 mrt 2008  jfs2.51.3.270769
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system      3140221 20 mei 2011  jfs2.51.3.282757
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system      1268973 16 okt 2012  jfs2.51.3.283899
```

No symbolic link at all.

Comment: Did you try [`procfiles -n`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds4%2Fprocfiles.htm)? [`lsof`](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/)?

Comment: @Gilles well I didn't knew about `procfiles -n` but if part of the GNU tools, I would have no access to them. with lsof though I never manage to get more than the PID

Comment: `procfiles` is a standard AIX command (follow my link). But if `lsof` can't do it then the information probably doesn't exist (except by working back from the inode and hoping that the executable hasn't been moved or deleted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so here's my answers to my questions.

- First: *Can I assume that the path of the proftpd is the first I'll find typing whereis as root ?*
  ==> NO, at least with my experience it shows no reliable information to determine the process executable path.
- Second: *How to determine executable path of a running process ?*
  I found a [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6428227/1195001) that state this possibility which is so far the only one that showed me the correct answer:
  `svmon -P <PID> -O format=nolimit,filename=on,filtertype=client`
  Problem with this command is that you have to wait until it shows you the information you want but it will probably give you the answer after a while. Another problem is that, this method can't be use in a script.
- Third:  *Concerning the "Why `ps -ef` is not showing neither a full nor a relative path"*
  <strike>The answer is probably (but feel free to correct me) that it shows the actual command typed by the user so if `root` was in a folder containing `proftpd` then it will only show `proftpd`</strike>
  No idea so far.

That's so far the best answer I can came up with.

---

**Edit 1**:

Scriptable way of finding the path of a running executable (this method doesn't come from me but from an no longer online forum).
Note that I will not provide a script because it's way over my capabilities and I have not the time right now.

- First step is to get the inode of your executable binary

  ```
  ls -i /proc/<PID>/object/a.out  |  cut -f 1 -d " "
  ```

  This command will output a  number.
- Then you need to identify the device on which your file is for that take a look at that command:

  ```
  ls -li /proc/<PID>/object/ | egrep "<inode>$"
  ```

  This command while give you a name of file like this : `jfs2.51.3.<inode>`.  `jfs2` is the filesystem type, `51` the major device number and `3` the minor device number.
- Once you identify the device info we need to identify the block device where the file is located with the following command :

  ```
  ls -l /dev/ | egrep "^b.*51, *3.+$"
  ```

  `^b.*51, *3.+$` `^b` is used to match block device
  `51, *3` matches the major block `51` followed by a comma and any space and minor block number `3` find previously.
  This command while give you something like :
  `brw-rw----    1 root     system       51,  3 24 feb 2009  myfilesystem`
- You can then identify the mount point of your block like this :

  ```
  df | grep myfilesystem
  /dev/myfilesystem     31457280    144544  100%   107442    81% /opts
  ```
- You now know where you need to search your  number:

  ```
  find /opts -inum <inode>
  ```

I admit this method is a bit complicated but it's the only one so far I found that is "easily scriptable". If someone ever write a script I'd glad to read it.

Comment: Copy your executable to any directory; `cd` to the directory and launch the executable with a relative path.  You can't assume anything.

Comment: @JRFerguson about what part of the answer you disagree ? I don't understand.

Comment: I disagree specifically over point-3.  Again, my disclaimer: I don't currently have access to an AIX machine.  I would hope that you found something useful in my offerings, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

```
getPathByPid()
{
    if [[ -e /proc/$1/object/a.out ]]; then
        inode=`ls -i /proc/$1/object/a.out 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            strnode=${inode}"$"
            strNum=`ls -li /proc/$1/object/ 2>/dev/null | grep $strnode | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\."`
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                # jfs2.10.6.5869
                n1=`echo $strNum|awk -F"." '{print $2}'`
                n2=`echo $strNum|awk -F"." '{print $3}'`
                # brw-rw----    1 root     system       10,  6 Aug 23 2013  hd9var
                strexp="^b.*"$n1,"[[:space:]]\{1,\}"$n2"[[:space:]]\{1,\}.*$"   # "^b.*10, \{1,\}5 \{1,\}.*$"
                strdf=`ls -l /dev/ | grep $strexp | awk '{print $NF}'`
                if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                    strMpath=`df | grep $strdf | awk '{print $NF}'`
                    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                        find $strMpath -inum $inode 2>/dev/null
                        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                            return 0
                        fi
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Too bad I didn't have a AIX no more at disposal or I would have tested this :D